# Responsive menu worked on local host wordpress but not once loaded to server

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I built a wordpress site on my local host but now when it's loaded to the server the responsive menu does not work, nor does the dropdown menu.
The link is http://davidmoorephotography.com.au/photos
I did try moving the .js scripts to the footer and removing from the header but that didn't work. I am using Wordpress 4.8

Comment: It looks like the site is currently offline. Have you tried opening the console (right-click inspect-element, console-tab) and seeing if there are any errors?  Is the live site different in any way from your local site? ie, does it have different plugins, &/or a different php version?

Comment: Also if you have issue just with your menu in mobile screens. It's probably as your js doesn't do anything on click over button, when you open console you can see lot's of 404.

Comment: Lastly you can add this code: `jQuery("button.navbar-toggle").click(function() { jQuery(".navbar-collapse").toggle(".collapse"); });` to make it work. But i insist to solve all 404 errors before, if it still does not work, go for this code.

Comment: Got the reason is your bootstrap.min.js is not found, you can see 404 error for that in console`(Cmd/Ctrl+Shift+I and then to Network)` of your browser. This are all the 404 you need to solve: http://i.imgur.com/Kxlesdr.png

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that many of the files are not found to the server.

Please ensure that you put all the .js files under js folder i.e `/js/filename.js`
and all the css files under DMPtheme i.e `/DMPtheme/filename.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like a routing issue, Make  sure all  your files are named correctally. If you are sure they are, their is something breaking it as it is not loading from your server. Perhaps you have two files named the same thing? If that fails revert back to the original code for your menu. Hope this helps.